# Como fazer o Auto Clomplete abrir a baixa da linha onde esta sendo digitado?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um sistema de auto complete e queria que as opções aparececem abaixa da linha onde o usuario esta digitando, como por exemplo editores de codigos como o **dreamweaver**.

**Auto Complete - Jquery:**

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "<a></a>",
  "<sub></sub>"
];
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" )
  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( "" );
      return false;
    }
  });
```

});

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="tags" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o atributo autoFocus para tal. Quando achar a palavra basta clicar no enter. Veja o exemplo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      autoFocus: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <textarea id="tags"></textarea>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1:**

Da uma olhada nesse plugin: http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/

Comment: não é isso que eu queria, eu queria q estas tags aparececem na linha abaixo na qual digitada, caso ele esteja digitando na linha 1, na linha 2 apareceria as tags para ele celecionar.

Comment: Não entendi, consegue colocar uma imagem anexa a tua pergunta?

Comment: ok, http://i.stack.imgur.com/RANnh.jpg, tipo assim q eu queria

Comment: O efeito que vc quer é o mesmo que postei. Pesquise por exemplo por 'java' e pressione o Enter o efeito será o mesmo

Comment: Observe que ele não é autocomplete simples, ele possui o recurso de foco no primeiro item da lista

Comment: desculpe a demora pois acabei me esquecendo desta pergunta :-/. Não oque eu queria era apenas a posição como de exemplo, tenho uma textarea com o height de 1500px e queria que o auto complete aparece abaixo da linha na qual esta digitando como na foto. Espero ter esclarecido, desculpem a demora

Comment: Veja o EDIT 1 pf